# List in Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I can't seem to easily access a list value from within a dictionary response from an API.

```
data = {
'room_id': room,
'how_many': 1
 }

 response_url = 'https://api.clickmeeting.com/v1/conferences/'+ str(room) +'/tokens'



 response1 = requests.post(response_url, headers=headers, data=data).  

 response1.raise_for_status()
 # access JSOn content
 jsonResponse = response1.json()

 print(jsonResponse)
```

the response is:
`{'access_tokens': [{'token': 'C63GJS', 'sent_to_email': None, 'first_use_date': None}]}`

I'm looking to assign the token value to a variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the list in `access_tokens` always of length 1?

Comment: `jsonResponse['access_tokens'][0]['token']` should let you print it out, I would recommend going in one step at a time so start with `print(jsonResponse['access_token'])` and then so on

Comment: How are you having trouble? Is there an error you are getting when you try to access it?

Comment: json_response[['access_token'][0]['token']

Comment: How would you do it if the data *didn't* come from a JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list in the `access_tokens` is always of length 1, you can do something like this:

```
token = json_response["access_token"][0]["token"]
```

If there's a potential for more than one item in `access_tokens`, then something similar:

```
tokens = []
access_tokens = json_response["access_token"]
tokens = [at["token"] if "token" in at for at in access_tokens]
```